# How to get specfic lines from a text file in C#

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

i have an text file with data like this
Input Data File Type : INdia.Txt

```
INdia(s) - Input Data File Exists .....

**------------------------------------------**
Feed Counts:
**------------------------------------------**
Records in the Input File            : 04686
Records Inserted in  Table : 04069
Records Inserted in  Table    : 00617
**-------------------------------------------**
```

i need to get only this data in the  output  file

```
Records in the Input File  : 04686
Records Inserted in  Table : 04069
Records Inserted in  Table    : 00617
```

code i am using

```
try
        {
            int NumberOfLines = 15;
            string[] ListLines = new string[NumberOfLines];
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"d:\Tesco\NGC\UtilityLogs\Store.log", FileMode.Open))
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    string line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(line);

                        if (line.Contains("Records"))
                        {
                            //Read the number of lines and put them in the array
                            for (int i = 8; i < NumberOfLines; i++)
                            {
                                ListLines[i] = reader.ReadLine();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
   while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
   {
      if(!line.Contains("Records"))  //if line does not contain "Records"
      {
         continue;  //skip to next line/iteration
      }

      //else
      //process the line  
   }
```

if the number of lines is known, then this could work

```
   int line_number = 1;
   int startline = 15;
   int endline = 100;
   while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
   {
      if(line_number >= startline && line_number <= endline)  
      {
         //process the line  
      }

      line_number++;
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

This LINQ query will give you `IEnumerable<string>` which will contain all lines from file, which start with "Records" string:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path).Where(line => line.StartsWith("Records"));
```

Comment: Ha! This is great! +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is of fixed contents then use INDEX.

Read the file with StreamReader then Split StreamReader Data by NEWLINE char, you will get an Array then put a Index for that array.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of rows in the file is the same all the time, use:

```
 string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

 string line1 = lines[5];
 string line2 = lines[6];
 string line3 = lines[6];
 ...
```

Or even something like this:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
string[] result = new string[3]; // No matter how many, but fixed

Array.Copy(lines, 5, result, result.Length);
```

You could even have a dynamic number of rows in case the header is always 5 lines and the file always ends with one line:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
string[] result = new string[lines.Length - 6];
Array.Copy(lines, 5, result, result.Length);
```